# "widmen" ohne Empfänger möglich?

Tags: word-usage, past-participle

Ist es möglich, auf eine Sache die gewidmet werden soll, nur den Stifter, ohne Empfänger zu schreiben?

Nach meiner Auffassung muss in einem Satz mit "gewidmet" immer der Empfänger kenntlich gemacht werden (oder bereits im Vorfeld klar sein).

Also beispielsweise:

> Dem Lehrer gewidmet. Von den Schülern.

und nicht:

> Gewidmet von den Schülern.

**Edit** (aus dem Kommentar):
Der Kontext, wo ich stutzig wurde, ist ein ganz anderer: "Gewidmet von den Mädchen" ist die Aufschrift auf einer Fahnenschleife, die bald in einem feierlichen Rahmen an eine Fahne angehangen wird.

Comment: "Gewidmet von den Mädchen" klingt für mich irgendwie so selbstzentriert, dass man da gleich "Gestiftet von den Mädchen" schreiben kann.

Comment: "Gestiftet von den Mädchen" ist meiner Empfindung nach sogar wesentlich besser. Dazu, was eine Widmung eigentlich ist, habe ich in meiner Antwort ja schon genug Geschrieben und eine Stiftung ist zwar auch eine Schenkung, die in dem Fall an einen Zweck gebunden ist, damit kann aber z.B. das Aufhängen an der Fahnenstange gemeint sein. Also stiften sie die Fahnenschleife, damit diese aufgehangen wird. Da braucht es nicht unbedingt einen benannten  Anlass/ Empfänger.

Answer (score 4):

Kurz gesagt: Nein

Erklärung:

Abgesehen davon, dass es sehr holprig klingt und mir nur Beispiele bekannt sind, in denen beide Seiten genannt werden oder sogar die Widmenden weggelassen werden, gibt es für das Wort "Widmung" drei Bedeutungen im Duden:

1. persönliche, in ein Buch, unter ein Bild o. Ä. geschriebene Worte
   [durch die kenntlich gemacht wird, dass es sich um ein Geschenk o.
   Ä. handelt]
2. Schenkung
3. Verwaltungsakt, durch den etwas zur öffentlichen Benutzung
   freigegeben und dem öffentlichen Recht unterstellt wird

Es geht hier zwar offensichtlich nicht um Punkt 1 aber ich will ihn trotzdem mit abdecken: Im Fall eines Autors, der z.B. bei einer Lesung sein Werk unterschreibt, spricht man nur dann von einer Widmung, wenn es persönlich ist also der Empfänger zumindest in einer Weise benannt ist (als Extrembeispiel: "Für meinen größten Fan"), andernfalls wäre es nur eine Signatur (Selbst wenn der Autor Exemplare verschenkt sind sie nur signiert, nicht gewidmet, solange nichts persönliches zum Empfänger drin steht). Im Fall eines z.B. Buches, das jemand kauft und einem anderen mit Widmung schenkt, trägt die Widmung eine persönliche Nachricht, die natürlich an den Adressaten (und wenn es nur ein "Ich wünsche Dir ..." ist) gerichtet sein muss.

Fall Zwei braucht offensichtlich einen Empfänger, denn eine Schenkung überträgt Eigentum zu einer (Rechts- oder natürlichen) Person hin.

Ich gehe mal davon aus, dass die Mädchen keinen Verwaltungsakt durchführen wollen und die Fahnenschleife nicht dem öffentlichen Recht unterstellt wird (Andernfalls ist der Empfänger - ggf. implizit - die Öffentlichkeit und kann in eine Formulierung evtl. weggelassen werden - wobei das im deutschen Recht garantiert geregelt ist). Trotzdem handelt es sich hier um eine Art Übertagung an eine Gemeinschaft also könnte man diese Defnintion im weiteren Sine anwenden. "Im weiteren Sinne" heißt aber, dass man sich nicht auf implizite Schlüsse stützen kann, außerdem ist der Zweck hier nicht die Bereitstellung von Stoffen sondern das Würdigen einer Person(-engruppe) oder eines Sachverhaltes.

Also nein, eine Widmung im eigentlichen Sinn kann nicht ohne Adressaten auskommen. Es ist natürlich möglich, das Wort anders zu verwenden, aber damit würde man das allgemeine Verständnis dieses Wortes untergraben und zumindest aus meiner Sicht eine große Häuchlerei begehen. Damit lenkt man nämlich den Fokus weg von Empfänger und Anlass und stattdessen hin zu den Widmenden. Gerade wenn man bedenkt, dass viele Widmungen ohne Nennung der Widmenden auskommen ("Den Gefallenen in Krieg/Schlacht XY", "Den Helden, die an Tag X unter Einsatz ihres Lebens Y Menschen vor Kataftrophe Z gerettet haben", "Meinem Lieben Freund", ...) ist das nicht der Sinn einer Widmung und vermutlich auch nicht im Sinne dieser Widmenden.

Answer (score 2):

Möglich ist es natürlich, aber sicherlich vor allem unüblich. So wie vom OP formuliert, wenn der Empfänger oder der Anlass klar ist, kann es natürlich weggelassen werden.

In dem konkreten Fall einer Fahnenschleife sollte es aber der Empfänger - oder in dem Fall eventuell auch der Anlass - mit aufgeführt werden. Denn natürlich ist gerade aktuell klar, warum "die Mädchen" die Fahnenschleife stiften. Aber in ein paar Jahren wird vielleicht niemand mehr wissen, zu welchem Ansatz die Schleife übergeben wurde und deshalb wird das üblicherweise mit auf die Fahnenschleife geschrieben.

Answer (score 2):

Das hängt sehr stark vom Zusammenhang ab. Wie IQV schon schrieb, sollte der Empfänger/Anlass der Widmung bekannt sein. Ich hatte erst die Vermutung, dass bei der Fahne schlicht die Wörter "widmen" und "stiften" verwechselt wurden; IQV hat diese Wörter in seiner Antwort auch ausgetauscht. Jedoch ist "widmen" und "stiften" nicht das Selbe: Eine Widmung hat den Empänger im Fokus, eine Stiftung den Stifter. In oben beschriebenen Fall nehmen ich jedoch an, dass "die Mädchen" die Flagge nicht gestiftet haben. Jedoch haben sie die besagte Fahne etwas bzw. jemandem gewidmet, was wohl der Grund ist warum die Widmenden explizit genannt werden. Es ist eindeutig eine sehr ungewöhnliche Form, jedoch in gewissen Zusammenhängen logisch.

Answer (score 0):

Die korrekte Variante ist natürlich:

> dem Lehrer seine treuen Schüler

[vide](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst-August-Denkmal#Beschreibung)